# Check if some object property exist in array of string typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have some array like this

```
const array1= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

const array2= [
{category: 'photos', code: 'A', fileName: '1664725062718.jpg', size: 120306},
{category: 'photos', code: 'F', fileName: '1664725062718.jpg', size: 120306},
{category: 'photos', code: 'K', fileName: '1664725062718.jpg', size: 120306},
];
```

I need some function that will check if any array member form **array1** exist in code property of **array2** and return true or false?

Something like this, of course this is just not working example?

```
array1.some(value => array2.includes(value))
```

Comment: `array1.some(value => array2.find(obj => obj.code === value))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a clean way is to do the "opposite" and use `some` on `array2`, destructuring `code` from each object, and then checking if the code is in the first array.

```js
const array1= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

const array2= [
{category: 'photos', code: 'A', fileName: '1664725062718.jpg', size: 120306},
{category: 'photos', code: 'F', fileName: '1664725062718.jpg', size: 120306},
{category: 'photos', code: 'K', fileName: '1664725062718.jpg', size: 120306},
{category: 'photos', code: null, fileName: '1664725062718.jpg', size: 120306},
];

// short-circuiting makes it shorter:
// console.log(array2.some(({ code }) => code && array1.includes(code)));
console.log(array2.some(({ code }) => code ? array1.includes(code) : false));
```

Comment: This is ok, but what is code is null, it will get error includes does nto accept null?

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Check if it is null before using `includes` then

Comment: Please write answer that i can accept, thanks

Comment: Probably worth at least noting that an array is a really poor choice of data structure for membership lookups. Array1 should really be an object or a set.